# Bash Comparing strings in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Hi I am trying to compare two strings in a directory. the format is as follows.

`{sametext}difference{sametext}`.

Note:  {sametext} is not static for each file

for example

`myfile_1_exercise.txt` compared to `myfile_2_exercise.txt`

Can you tell me how I would match the above strings in an if statement.

Basically I need to know how I would ignore the number in the two strings so that these would be same.

Some example code is shown below:

My example code looks like this:

```
for g in `ls -d */`;
do                      
  if [ -d $g ]; then 
    cd $g                 # down 1 directories
    for h in `ls *root`;
    do
      printf "${Process[${count}]} = ${basedir}/${f}${g}${h}\n"
      h1=${h}

      if [ "${h1}" = "${h2}" ]; then # NEED to MATCH SOME HOW??????????
        echo we have a match
      fi

      h2=${h1}
      let count+=1
    done

    cd ../
    #printf "\n\n\n\n"      
  fi
done
```

What should be the test to determine this instead of `"${h1}" = "${h2}"`?

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: When you say `strings in a directory`, are you actually referring to filenames?

Comment: I've read your post 3 times and still have no idea, what is you question.

Comment: Is the `{sametext}` piece going to depend on the file, or is it some static value like `myfile`?

In other words, would you only look at files that start with `myfile`... ?

Comment: Your test of "${h1}" = "${h2}" should work fine for comparing strings using the test command (also known as left square bracket). But of course h2 is empty the first time through.

Comment: Sorr namuol the {sametext} is not static.

Comment: Do you only need to ignore numbers in the filename? or is there a different template at work here, eg. ignore whatever is between the first and last `_` underscore character?

Comment: Hi Rob. "${h1}" = "${h2}" will not match as they are the next filename in the list of filenames. How would I match  "file_1_test.txt" and "file_2_test.txt". I would need a will card between "file_*_test.txt"

Comment: Ah, so you've updated the question to clarify that you want myfile_1_exercise.txt to compare equal to myfile_2_exercise.txt. Will all of your filenames have this same format, myfile_X_exercise.txt, where X is a number? That would simplify things.

Comment: HI Rob. Yes the files will have the same format. I would like to use wildcards if possible so...  filename=myfile_X_exercise.txt   ${filename%%*} I know this is wrong, but this method would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"myfile_1_exercise.txt" == "myfile_2_exercise.txt"
```

You mean the above test should return `true` (ignoring the numbers) right?
This is what I would have done:

```
h1="myfile_1_exercise.txt"
h2="myfile_2_exercise.txt"
if [ $( echo ${h1} | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' ) == $( echo ${h2} | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' ) ] ; then 
    # do something here.
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` comes in handy here.

This basically goes through every file in the directory, extracts the two strings from the filename, and keeps a list of all the unique combinations thereof.

Then, it walks through this list, and uses bash's wildcard expansion to allow you to loop over each collection.

EDIT: Got rid of an ugly hack.

```
i=0
for f in *_*_*.txt
do
    a=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\)_.*_\(.*\).txt/\1/g'`
    b=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\)_.*_\(.*\).txt/\2/g'`

    tmp=${all[@]}
    expr match "$tmp" ".*$a:$b.*" >/dev/null
    if [ "$?" == "1" ]
    then
      all[i]="$a:$b"
      let i+=1
    fi
done

for f in ${all[@]}
do
    a=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/\1/g'`
    b=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/\2/g'`
    echo $a - $b
    for f2 in $a_*_$b.txt
    do
        echo "  $f2"
        # ...
    done
done
```

Of course, this assumes that all the files you care about follow the `*_*_*.txt` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer:

1. Mileage can vary and you may have to adjust and debug the script for corner cases.
2. You may be better off using Perl for your task.
3. There could be better solutions even in Bash. This one is not very efficient but it seems to work.

Said that, here is a script that compares two strings according to your requirements. I am sure you can figure how to use it in your directory listing script (for which you may want to consider `find` by the way)

This script takes two strings and prints match! if they match

```
$ bash compare.sh myfile_1_exercise.txt myfile_2_exercise.txt
match!
$ bash compare.sh myfile_1_exercise.txt otherfile_2_exercise.txt
$
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname1=$1
fname2=$2

findStartMatch() {
  match=""
  rest1=$1 ;
  rest2=$2 ;
  char1=""
  char2=""
  while [[  "$rest1" != "" && "$rest2" != "" && "$char1" == "$char2" ]] ; do
    char1=$(echo $rest1 | sed 's/\(.\).*/\1/');
    rest1=$(echo $rest1 | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/') ;
    char2=$(echo $rest2 | sed 's/\(.\).*/\1/');
    rest2=$(echo $rest2 | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/') ;
    if [[ "$char1" == "$char2" ]] ; then
      match="${match}${char1}"
    fi
  done
}

findEndMatch() {
  match=""
  rest1=$1 ;
  rest2=$2 ;
  char1=""
  char2=""
  while [[  "$rest1" != "" && "$rest2" != "" && "$char1" == "$char2" ]] ; do
    char1=$(echo $rest1 | sed 's/.*\(.\)/\1/');
    rest1=$(echo $rest1 | sed 's/\(.*\)./\1/') ;
    char2=$(echo $rest2 | sed 's/.*\(.\)/\1/');
    rest2=$(echo $rest2 | sed 's/\(.*\)./\1/') ;
    if [[ "$char1" == "$char2" ]] ; then
      match="${char1}${match}"
    fi
  done
}

findStartMatch $fname1 $fname2
startMatch=$match
findEndMatch $fname1 $fname2
endMatch=$match

if [[ "$startMatch" != "" && "$endMatch" != "" ]] ; then
  echo "match!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually comparing two files like you mentiond ... probably you can use `diff` command like

```
diff myfile_1_exercise.txt myfile_2_exercise.txt
```

Comment: Sorry Rahul I am comparing the filenames. Not the file content. Sorry I should have be more clear